# How to search strings in Python using a wildcard that represents only a single word -- and not multiple words as well?

Tags: python, string, search, substring, wildcard

fnmatch is pretty simple in Python -- however it will output "True" whether there is 1, or 100 words, between the words you've put the wildcard between.

I'd like to be more narrow than this -- and be able to use some kind of wildcard searching library that let's me specify HOW MANY words I want to be wildcards.

So if I used: "the * cat", it would ONLY include single words like "the ugly cat" or "the furry cat"

But if I used something like: "the ** cat", it would include ONLY two words like "the very ugly cat" or "the extremely furry cat"

Is there any python library that allows this kind of fine-tuned wildcard functionality?

Thanks!

Comment: What makes a continuous string of characters (no spaces) "not a word"? Do hyphenated words count as one or two? Can it have numbers

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the obvious fix is to put a space between the wildcards if that's what you mean.

Secondly, a wildcard also matches a space, so you need to say something different if you mean something different.

A regular expression which matches a "word" is `\w+` so you could rearticulate your code as

```
import re

for match in re.findall(r"the \w+ \w+ cat", text):
    print(match)
```

If you want to support the `*` wildcard and otherwise only match literal text, try something like

```
pattern = "the * * cat"
regex = '\w+'.join(re.escape(fragment) for fragment in pattern.split('*'))
for match in re.findall(regex, text):
    print(match)
```